# How to share one static variable with multiple translation unit?

Tags: c++, c

I want to make an array static and also want to reference it in the other translation unit. Then I define it as `static int array[100] = {...}`, and declare it in other translation unit as `extern int array[]`. But the compiler tells me that the storage class of static and extern conflict with each other, how could I pass it and still reach my goal?

Comment: At what point did you decide that you needed to "make the array static"?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think most people think that a global `static` variable would mean the same thing as making a class variable `static` or making a local variable in a function `static`. It's an understandable mistake, but it doesn't even do nearly that.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615192/why-does-the-static-keyword-have-so-many-meanings-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `static`. Just have the `int array[100] = {...};` in one .cpp file, and have `extern int array[100];` in the header file.

`static` in this context means that other translation units can't see it. That obviously conflicts with the `extern` directive.

Answer (score 2):

`static` in file scope is pretty much a declare-private directive to the assembler. It is most certainly different than `static` in class or function scope.

E.g. in zlib, `#define LOCAL static` is used.

Comment: What has the assembler to do with anything? Did you mean the "linker"?

Comment: No, assembler. The assembler creates the symbol table. I'm certain `gcc -c` and similar don't involve the linker.

Comment: I see. In any event, there's no "assembly stage" in the language standard, only "linkage types" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the variable global, consider leaving it static and adding public accessors and modifiers to it.  It's not a great thing to directly couple to naked variables in other modules.

Comment: Through the 2023 retrospectoscope this seems like pretty bad advice :)