# Static array indices in function parameter declarations

Tags: c++, c

Thanks to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function) question I understand what this construct does and how it can be used.

What I don't get is why is it missing from C++? Does it conflict with another feature? Was it replaced with something better? Does the standard say anything about this?

Comment: Remember, C++ is not C, and C is not C++. C++ started out as an extension of C, but has long since evolved down its own path. Sometimes they "borrow" ideas from each other, but they are completely separate languages.

Comment: I understand this. What I'm asking is why was this specific feature left out instead of another

Comment: It wasn't left out.  It was added in C99 (I believe), and C++ has been around since the early 80s

Comment: For that you simply have to as the C++ standards committee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ was standardized before this feature was standard in C. There is no general process of migrating new C features to C++, although some are on a case-by-case basis.

You aren't really expected to do this in C++. If you think you want to pass a pointer to the first element of an array you can instead pass either a `vector` by reference, or pass one or a pair of iterators. That is to say: don't try to decorate raw pointers, instead browse C++'s vast menu of types.

Presumably it would be useful when writing dual-language header files, if C++ supported all the declaration syntax that C supports. I haven't done that in a long time, though, so I don't know what the best alternative is. You'd probably get away with just declaring it as a `char*` in the C++ header, but I'm not sure whether that conforms to standards.