# Terminology for array where length is known C/C++

Tags: c

In C, you can have an array defined locally on in a struct where the length is known.

eg:

```
{
    int foo[8];
    assert(sizeof(foo) == sizeof(int[8]));
    ...
```

When used in a struct, the array size is also known.

```
struct MyStruct { int foo[8]; };
void func(struct MyStruct *mystruct)
{
    assert(sizeof(mystruct->foo) == sizeof(int[8]));
```

However when passed as an argument to a function, this is equivalent to an `int *`.

```
void func(int foo[8])
{
    assert(sizeof(foo) == sizeof(int[8]));  /* will fail */
```

---

This is of course correct and to be expected, my question is - whats the terminology to use when referring to the difference?

eg, what would be the correct completion of this comment?

```
/* This macro will only work correctly when ____ */
#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
```

Answer (score 4):

As you said, in C, a pointer to the array is passed to a function, and so you can't find its size using the `sizeof` operator at all.

The comment is wrong to start with, it should be:

```
/* This macro will only work correctly if 'a' is an array type */
```

Comment: nitpick: a pointer to the *first element of the array* is passed

Comment: Only if the function parameter is a pointer. The thing is that it OP's code the function parameter *is* `int*`.

Comment: Even if the function parameter is declared as an array, its actual type is pointer, not array. and so sizeof will return the size of the pointer.

Comment: @MByD Right, so in that case the function parameter is a pointer, and an array may decay.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays *decay* into pointers when passed in to functions. The comment might be:

```
/* This macro will only work correctly when the array is not decayed */
```

Comment: @juanchopanza: Is it possible to have a function argument thats an array?, The only way I've seen arrays pass-by-value, is by wrapping them into a `struct`.

Comment: @ideasman42 You can have functions whose *parameter* is a pointer to array.

Answer (score 2):

Function parameters cannot have array type. The declaration

```
void func(int foo[8])
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
void func(int *foo)
```

discarding any size information (except in case of the declaration `int foo[static 8]` - the type will still be adjusted to `int*`, but the compiler may use the size information for optimization purposes).

Note that in addition to arrays of statically known size, there are also variable-length arrays of dynamic size and incomplete arrays of unknown size. The latter can only appear in external declarations (as storage requirements are unknown) or within a struct as a flexible array member.

In case of variable-length arrays, `sizeof` has to be evaluated at runtime, in case of incomplete arrays, it should fail to compile.

So if you want to be specific, your comment could be written as:

> This macro will only work correctly when 'a' has complete array type
>   and in particular is not a function parameter as those have pointer type.

Comment: Note, even though you dont say it does: using `int foo[static 8]` doesnt change behavior wrt `sizeof`. maybe worth noting for clarity

Comment: Also maybe worth linking to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function

Comment: @ideasman42: I explicitly mentioned that *the type will still be adjusted*, but nevertheless I clarified

Comment: Note, you use the phrase *"adjusted to `int`"* but it seems there is a more precise term in this context: **"decay"** - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Comment: @ideasman42: the C standard defines *adjustment* of parameter types, *promotion* of arguments and operands and *conversion* of lvalues, arrays and function designators; *decay* is a colloquial term for automatic conversion of expressions with array type, which is different from parameter adjustment

Comment: @ideasman42 No, the terminology is correct here. The function parameter gets *adjusted* to pointer, meaning the function signature is exactly `void func(int *foo)`. An array name passed as *argument* to this function would undergo *decay*.

Comment: @juanchopanza, wrt your last comment, This is quite an important distinction and think its worth noting in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

/* This macro will only work correctly when **"a" is a complete type array** */

Because you can not use `sizeof` with an incomplete type:

```
struct T {
    int a;
    int arr[]; /* Flexible array */
};

int main(void)
{
    struct T x;

    /* invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘int[]’ */    
    printf("%zu\n", ARRAY_SIZE(x.arr)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: any array is indexable as array subscription is sugar for pointer arithmetics