# What does static mean in int[static 10]?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99

I found a rather strange and unfamiliar usage of the `static` keyword in C99 and could not find in the language specs nor by experimentation what does it mean:

```
void set(int t[static 10], int size)
{
    // do something with t, not important here
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {
        t[i] = size + i;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[It compiles and run fine (demo on repl.it)](https://repl.it/Lh08)</kbd>

My question is then: **what does the `static` keyword mean in C99 when applied to an array size?**

---

Note: the following is illegal:

```
int t5[static 10];
```

> error: static or type qualifiers in non-parameter array declarator

Comment: Never mind, I found a perfect duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/what-is-the-purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function-like-char

Comment: [This array declaration reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) should be helpful.

Comment: I search SO for like one hour with all the possible ways to express my question without luck. I write the question: BAM! related question is perfect duplicate. Thanks SO.

Comment: It means that the array passed must contain at least 10 elements (and it can't be a NULL pointer).

Comment: The duplicate is good but what it doesn't mention is the actual language spec, found in C11 6.7.6.2:

Comment: `In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the [ and ] may delimit
an expression or *. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an incomplete or function
type. The optional type qualifiers and the keyword static shall appear only in a
declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost
array type derivation.`

Comment: @Lundin maybe you should add it to the duplicate for completeness.