# Why does "static" keyword have such varied usage in C?

Tags: c, static, compiler-construction

I'm familiar with several uses for the keyword "static" in C:

- Static variables within a function will maintain their value between function calls.
- Static (global) variables in a file cannot be accessed outside the file they're declared in.
- Static functions cannot be accessed outside the file they're declared in.
- [This obscure use as part of an array type declaration as an argument to a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/what-is-the-purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function-like-char)

The first use has to do with an entity's *lifetime*, the second and third uses have to do with an entity's *visibility*, the fourth use has to do with *optimization*, and it seems strange to me that one keyword would act so differently depending on where it is used.  Is there some strange detail of how static is usually implemented in compilers that makes it easy for this one keyword to do all of the above?  What is the underlying functionality that "static" provides which results in these varied behaviors?

Comment: I think this is mainly a result of avoiding introduction of new keywords to the language at all costs.

Comment: Nothing to understand here. The language is designed this way. You may also ask why `to have` has so many meanings and functions in English.

Comment: Hey,  `const` is another candidate.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is now closed and the duplicate is closed as well... C Committee tried to limit the introduction of new keywords for compatibility with existing code that used the keyword as an identifier. They tried to overwork or overload existing keywords as much as possible.

Comment: Quoting C Rationale document: *"Where possible, however, new features have been added by overloading existing keywords, as, for example, long double instead of extended. It is recognized that each added keyword will require some existing code that used it as an identifier to be rewritten. No meaningful programs are known to be quietly changed by adding the new keywords."*

Comment: They also admitted it causes some confusion for storage-class specifier. *"C89 separated from the overloaded keywords for storage classes the various concepts of scope, linkage, name space, and storage duration. This has traditionally been a major area of confusion."*

Comment: Decisions 1-3 were taken not by the C committee but by Kernighan and Ritchie. Unfortunately. Probably a mishmash of opinion and backwards compatibility. Off topic.

Comment: Thanks for the informative comments! I understand that my question is a duplicate (oops!) but shouldn't one of the two questions be open for new answers?

Comment: Then you get to C++ and class members... :((   OP is right - there is too much keyword overloading in these languages:(