# C: passing an array of fixed size to function vs passing pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

in the man page for the `pipe` system call, I see

```
       /* On all other architectures */
       int pipe(int pipefd[2]);

       #define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
       #include <fcntl.h>              /* Obtain O_* constant definitions */
       #include <unistd.h>

       int pipe2(int pipefd[2], int flags);
```

the functions accept an array with a fixed size as their arguments `int pipe(int pipefd[2])` but I know that in C you cannot pass an array as an argument because it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array. This question is mostly aimed at getting coding advice: I always use this signature: `func(int *array, int len)` whenever passing an array comes up in my programming, so I was wondering when would something like this be useful? The only use case I can think of is letting the user of the API know that you must pass an array sized for 2 elements (in this case), but from a quick compilation test, I can see that `gcc` does not complain when a mismatch occurs:

```
void func(int array[10])
{
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[4]; // passing int[4] but expected int[10]
    func(array);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc` compiles the above code without errors or warnings. Any insight is welcome.

Comment: *the functions accept an array with a fixed size as their arguments int pipe(int pipefd[2])* -- No it doesn't.  That signature is exactly the same as `pipe(int* pipefd)`.

Comment: Do note that does not mean arrays are pointers, they are not.  It is just that array types in function parameters decay into a pointer to the element type.  This is called array decay.

Comment: Arrays when passed to a function decay to a pointer.  That `[]` syntax you are using in the function signature is only used for the purpose of documenting the code a little better.

Comment: `func(int *array, int len)` would be to pass array of any length; here, we expect only a array of 2 elements i.e, only `array[0]` and `array[1]` are used.

Comment: related (not dup): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430315/what-is-the-purpose-of-static-keyword-in-array-parameter-of-function-like-char

Comment: The API for `pipe` is really awkward. If you are looking for inspiration of how to write proper C, do not look at old skunky Unix libraries designed during the Jurassic period... in fact do not look at *nix at all. I'm having a hard time naming a single well-designed library among the most used ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void func (int *array, int len)` is pretty idiomatic C so using that style is never wrong. Mind "const correctness" however, in case the function doesn't modify the contents.

You can use a fixed size array parameter if it makes sense to only ever accept such arrays. It is self-documenting code but as you noticed, it doesn't actually improve type safety since the array is adjusted to a pointer to the first element no matter. (Which is in fact why we can even write `int param[]` with an incomplete array size.)

You *could* improve type safety by requiring a pointer to the array instead:

```
void func(int (*array)[10])
{
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[4]; 
    func(&array); // compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

But using array pointers as part of the function API is odd and unusual - it might make the code harder to read. And this makes "const correctness" impossible as well.

The best combination of readability and type safety might be to use a pointer to variable-sized array instead:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void func (size_t size, int array[size])
{
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[3]; 
    func(4, array); // warning from gcc here
    return 0;
}
```

This pushes the responsibility of keeping track of the array size onto the caller and some compilers may produce warnings in case it has a chance to spot mismatch at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it doesn't comply, because the array size is not specified.  The array size indeed is used to indicate the number of elements of the array.  Of course, in C you can pass an array bigger than that, because C doesn't check array bounds and the array decays to a pointer.

But you cannot pass an array smaller, as the problem is that `pipe()` is an interface to the kernel, and there's no way to check what you have used the memory after the array for, and the kernel will get that as valid and will write on it the two file descriptors (which will be two, except in case some resource is violated and the `pipe(2)` system call fails)  This means that if you pass e.g. an array of 1 element, in the place where the second element would go, the file descriptor will be written by the kernel and undefined behaviour will came in your assistance.... probably a crash.